# Inserting Javascript code into a ScriptElement to set Window vars

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

In GWT how do I make this Javascript into a ScriptElement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
addthis_config.pubid = 'YOUR-PUBID';
$.getScript( "https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#domready=1");
</script>
```

The solution I know is for:

```
  ScriptElement script = doc.createScriptElement();
  script.setSrc("https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#domready=1");
```

However how about the `addthis_config` and `addthis_config.pubid` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the `ScriptElement` you have to inject it to the `DOM` in order to load the 3rd-party script, but this is not the normal way to load scripts in GWT.

Normally in GWT we use the `ScriptInjector`, but in your case, you have to use previously some `JSNI` code to set those vars in the window object:

```
final static String AT_PUBID = "YOUR-PUBID";
final static String AT_URL = "https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#domready=1";

public void onModuleLoad() {
  setAddthisId(AT_PUBID);
  ScriptInjector.fromUrl(AT_URL).inject();
}

private static native void setAddthisId(String id) /*-{
  $wnd.addthis_config = $wnd.addthis_config||{};
  $wnd.addthis_config.pubid = id;
}-*/;
```

You could even inject your javascript code as a string using `ScriptInjector` as well, but IMO this is a nasty solution since GWT compiler cannot perform any JSNI syntax checking:

```
....
ScriptInjector.fromString(
   "$wnd.addthis_config = $wnd.addthis_config||{};" +
   "$wnd.addthis_config.pubid = '+ " AT_PUBID + "';"
).inject();
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(AT_URL).inject();
```

If you actually prefer not to use `JSNI` at all to avoid dealing with javascript mistakes, I would suggest to use the [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) library, which apart from dozens of features allows you to manipulate DOM elements with a very simple syntax:

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
....

$(window).prop("addthis_config", $$("pubid: " + AT_PUBID));
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(AT_URL).inject();
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to set multiple variables with $(window)

Comment: Like `window.var1 = 'a', window.var2 = 'b'` ... ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that

Comment: With GQuery: `$(window).prop("var1", "a");` `$(window).prop("var2", "b");`